# Cannot run the selected program/Script in selenium webdriver

Tags: eclipse, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am unable to run some of the classes in my project.After opening the class if i mouse over on Run button its showing different class that i executed previously.I am unable to run the class I opened and one thing i observed is the class which i am unable to run is used as extended class for other classes.Please help me out with this issue and suggest me if i need to change any Run configuration settings?.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hlKXO.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no test or main method to run which is why you are not seeing any option to run..either mark that f method with @Test or any other annotation from testng or create a main method

Comment: Yes!Now i am able to run after adding Annotation.Thanks!!

Comment: if this helps then please accept this as answer so that others looking for such queries can find it easy